# Speeding up a grouby sum function on a custom rolling time interval window in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the rolling sum of values according to a multindex over a predefined interval such as year (basically, a rolling annual sum). The data is strucutured below, where the index has two levels, rdate and pdate:

```
                        Value   Desired Result
Reference   Published       
2009-06-30 2009-07-31   745.000    745.000
           2009-08-13   745.000    745.000
2009-09-30 2009-10-30     0.000    745.000
2009-12-31 2010-02-05   496.000   1241.000
           2010-03-02   496.000   1241.000
2010-03-31 2010-04-30    80.000   1321.000
2010-06-30 2010-07-30    30.000    606.000
2010-09-30 2010-11-03  -110.000    496.000
           2010-11-07   437.000   1043.000
2010-12-31 2011-02-04   440.000   1483.000
2011-03-31 2011-05-05  1031.000   1938.000
2011-06-30 2011-07-29    53.000   1961.000
2011-09-30 2011-11-04     2.000   1526.000
2011-12-31 2012-02-03  -191.000    895.000
```

I am new to pandas, so I may be missing some easy functionality or optimizations but here is my solution:

```
def sum_func(df):
    tmp = []
    df = df.to_frame()
    for ((rdate, pdate),value) in df.itertuples():
        t0 = rdate - pd.DateOffset(years=1,days=1)
        tmp += [df.loc(axis=0)[t0:rdate,t0:pdate].groupby(level=0,axis=0).tail(1).sum(skipna=False)]
    return pd.DataFrame(tmp, index=df.index)
```

However, it seems to be pretty slow:

```
%timeit sum_func(test_df)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.2 ms per loop
```

I will need to run it thousands of time for larger datasets, so I need a fast solution. I have installed numexpr and bottleneck. The indexing and grouping is 92.5% of the time so I guess the major optimizations are to be made there:

```
%lprun -f sum_func sum_func(test_df)

Timer unit: 3.42123e-07 s

Total time: 0.0825231 s
File: <ipython-input-38-b6071946e5e0>
Function: sum_func at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def sum_func(df):
     2         1            5      5.0      0.0      tmp = []
     3         1         1884   1884.0      0.8      df = df.to_frame()
     4        21          965     46.0      0.4      for ((rdate, pdate),value) in df.itertuples():
     5        20        10867    543.4      4.5          t0 = rdate - pd.DateOffset(years=1,days=1)
     6        20       223104  11155.2     92.5          tmp += [df.loc(axis=0)[t0:rdate,t0:pdate].groupby(level=0,axis=0).tail(1).sum(skipna=False)]
     7         1         4384   4384.0      1.8      return pd.DataFrame(tmp, index=df.index)
```

Edit:

Managed to condense all into one line, but still not much faster:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import QuarterBegin
def stm(ddf):
    return pd.DataFrame(map(lambda (_,t0): 
               ddf.loc(axis=0)[:, (t0-QuarterBegin(4)):t0].groupby(level=0,axis=0).tail(1).sum(skipna=False), ddf.index),
                index=ddf.index)
```

Reduced by almost 25%:

```
%timeit stm(test_df)
10 loops, best of 3: 37.6 ms per loop
```

Maybe there is a faster indexing in pandas? Any help? Thanks

Comment: I guess http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is appropriate place.

Comment: I try to demonstrate your approaches, but each method returned different output - no one desired output. Why?

Comment: jezrael, there was a data issue with the dates and values.. now it should work fine.. sorry about that